# How to make a phonebook directory in python uisng linkedlist

Tags: python, list, class, linked-list, directory

so im trying to make a phonebook directory in python using linked list but i dont know how to add the name and the number
As well as other functions
P.S my knowledge in python is not that solid and only a second year college
I need a help with this one

`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name=" ",number=None):
       self.name = name
       self.number = number
       self.next = None
 
 
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def Insert(self,name,number):
        pass 
        
    def View(self,name,number):
        pass 
    
    def Update(self,name,number):
        pass
        
    def Delete(self,name,number):
        pass
        
        
        
    def display(self):
        pass
            
            
a_llist = LinkedList()
 
print('**********Menu***********')
print(" press [I] Insert Contact")
print(" press [V] View  Contact")
print(" press [U] Update Contact")
print(" press [D] Delete Contact")
print(" press [X] Exit")

while True:
    ch=str(input("Enter your choice :"))
    if ch=='I' or ch== 'i': # to add a contact
        
        insrt=int(input("How many contacts you want to add? :"))
        for i in range(insrt):
            name=str(input("Enter name :"))
            num=int(input("Enter number :"))
            
    
        
    elif ch=='V' or ch== 'v':
        # to view the contacts that's been added
    
    elif ch=='U' or ch== 'u':
        # to update a contact 
        #like to change the number or name
        
    elif ch=='D' or ch=='d':
        # to delete a contact
        
    elif ch=='X' or ch== 'x':
        #to exit the program 
        
    else :
        print("invalid option ")
```

Heres the code ive done so far

Comment: *"Heres the code ive done so far"*: It looks like you have posted the template code, and forgot to show what you have done and where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Insert, view, update, and delete have already been implemented, just search for them on Google. You just need to implement the operations inside of a function. I have a sample code here for inserting a value, just for your information.

```
name = input("Enter name:")
list = []
contact = input("Enter new Contact: ")
list.append(contact)
list.insert(0,name)
ll.insert(contact)
ll.display()
```

Simply insert it into the linked list using the arbitrary or *. It will insert multiple values into only one node (one address).

```
def Insert(self, *newnode):
    pass
```

Linked List operations are already implemented, and you can search for them on Google.

By the way, we might be classmates because we both have a phone book directory that uses linked lists, and I am a second-year evening IT student at CTU and this project was given by Ma'am U.

Comment: But I think an arbitrary in insertion is unnecessary because it takes only one argument. However, if you want to separate the name and number, you can use an arbitrary. and I thank you.